# IE: cannot preset default input value after add class attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

Here is a input dom object that I try to add default value:

```
<input type="text" name="amount0" id="_amount_id_0" value="0" />
```

and it works, but after add the class attribute

```
<input type="text" name="amount0" id="_amount_id_0" class="itemAmount" value="0" />
```

Default vaule 0 is gone on UI.

So what is the work around?

Comment: Just to clarify...you are adding the class with Javascript, or just in the static HTML?  When you say the value is gone, do you mean it is not visible in the UI, or something is removing it from the DOM as well?  Maybe that class has some css rules making the text color same as the background color?  Seems like a stretch, but something to check.

Comment: Make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) demo with all your HTML/CSS/JavaScript and also tell us what version of IE you are using.